# how to insert server time to database using mysql

Tags: mysql

i want to insert server time to table.i will use mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOW()`. It's a MySQL function.

This assumes your database is on the same server as your main server.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOW()` as Kerry says. If you're using PHP and don't want the MySQL server time but the PHP time, use this:

```
$time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$query = "INSERT INTO example(timefield) VALUES('$time');";
```